# Image with src inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a template like this

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <img src="{{product.Link}}" />
    .....
</div>
```

Each time this is regenerated it results in the browser clearing out the img and placing it back in again and will therefore redownload from source. The result is clunky looking ajax. How do I place an image inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: Use ng-src instead of src

Comment: seems reasonable but there is still a rather large jump and the image is still downloaded again.

Comment: The only consistent way I know of pre-loading an image is to create an image dom element that is either off the screen or not visible causing the browser to download the image. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ngSrc directive. It it used to get around this exact issue.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: would this not be basically a hack? ... you build a framework on top of a base code that breaks the functionality of the base code, and so you have to create a special band-aid to repair it ..

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer is incorrect and i can't comment ill make a new answer.

The correct answer is to use `track by`

For example

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
    <img src="{{product.Link}}" />
    .....
</div>
```

this causes the elements and images not to be redrawn but rather just the changes.